# Doubling theorem for Alexandrov spaces

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Is there a user friendly exposition of the notion of boundary of an Alexandrov space with curvature bounded from below and of the Doubling theorem?

The only reference I am aware of is the original preprint by Perelman which is not very user friendly to my taste (though I am not an expert in the area).

Comment: Perelman's doubling theorem is generalized in [S.Alexander and R.Bishop "Curvature bounds for warped products of metric spaces, (GAFA) 14 (2004) 1143-1181.] See http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~sba/wp.pdf.